# Add custom button in myaccount users page in woocommerce plugin

Tags: woocommerce

After clicking on Users -> Edit User , I want to create a custom button in users page next to Update button.Which action should be written inside our functions.php page

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress not provided any hook to add a custom button in WordPress user edit interface but we can add it by hook using jquery. Button action we can implement by using function action admin_init.

```
add_action('admin_head','add_button_profile');

function add_button_profile( $checkout ) { 

        if(isset($_GET['user_id']) && !empty($_GET['user_id'])){    

?>
        <script type="text/javascript">    

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                    jQuery(".submit #submit").after('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input 

id="customButton" class="button button-primary" name="customsubmit" 


value="Custom Button" type="submit">');

                });

        </script>    
<?php }

}

add_action('init','custom_button_function');

function custom_button_function() { 

    if(is_admin() && isset($_POST['customsubmit']) && ($_POST['customsubmit']

 == 'Custom Button')){

        #####You can create button action here
    }
}
```